# Creating a schedule task that copies file from one location to another and puts them in a specifically named folder

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

Hello Stackoverflow I am working with a completely new problem here, my scenario is on a daily basis I get for example two file format; `.txt and .csv`, I want to write a task scheduler script that copies these files for each month, creates a folder that reflects that month and year so for example if is have files (both `.txt and .csv` format) for the month of November 2014, they are placed in a folder named `November 2014`
As stated initially its something I want to develop, are their any recommendations in how I can achieve this,Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Just create console application, that will perform your copy once, on start and schedule it with Windows Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

- Build your schedule login using timers.
- Use the windows task scheduler to call your app on schedule.
- Use something like quartz scheduler to build schedule in your app.